# Alamofire multipartFormData upload doesn't send data

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to upload an image using Alamofire but the server is not getting the image.
This is the code where I make the upload:

```
Alamofire.upload(Router.UpdateUserAvatar,
        multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) -> Void in
            let compressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.8
            guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality) else {
                print("Unable to get JPEG representation for image \(image)")
                callCompletion()
                return
            }
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: ParameterKey.Avatar, mimeType: "image/jpeg")

        }, encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) -> Void in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(request: _, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):
                finalResult = Result.Success(self)
                callCompletion()
            case .Failure(let errorType):
                let error = errorType as NSError
                finalResult = Result.failureForError(error, data: nil)
                callCompletion()
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After almost 4 hours looking into this I found out that the API needed the file name too, here's the line I changed and everything worked.

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: ParameterKey.Avatar, fileName: "avatar.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing this! It works for me too. But little confuse me now, why I need to give this file a name, since I will never use it on the server side. May some server tweak helps `appendBodyPart` to work without redundant `fileName` parameter?..

Comment: In my case it was because the library that we are using in the server side requires the name even if we don't use it.

Comment: how about audio file in Alamofire 4? - i try to send a audio file in this form : multipartFormData.append(audioLocalPath, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "application/octet-stream") but occur this error : multipartEncodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.MultipartEncodingFailureReason.bodyPartFileNotReachableWithError(file:///var/mobile/Containers/....... /Documents/item.mp3, NSUnderlyingError=0x16049100 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})) - where is problem? -bad request or bad audio path?

Comment: @Saeid for the error that you are posting `{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}`, it looks like the problem is the path to the audio